# How to send dynamic variable to partials page "sidebar"?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a partial page "sidebar" that shows up in every page. There my logo is dynamic. To display my logo i have send variable through my dashboard controller but it says undefined variable.
The problem seems to be in route because "/dashboard" is being called not the "sidebar"
For sidebar i have wrote its part in dashboard controller
So, how can i make this work?

> Undefined variable: logos (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\odan\resources\views\admin\partials\sidebar\sidebar.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\odan\resources\views\admin\partials\sidebar\sidebar.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\odan\resources\views\admin\partials\sidebar\sidebar.blade.php)

**Dashboard controller**

```
public function sidebar()
{
    $data['logos'] = Setting::first();

    return view('admin.layouts.app', $data);
}
```

**Sidebar.blade.php**

```
<!-- Brand Logo -->
  <a href="index3.html" class="brand-link">
    <img src="{{asset('uploaded/'.optional($logos)->image)}}" alt="Odan Logo" 
     class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3" style="opacity:.8">
    <span class="brand-text font-weight-light">Odan</span>
  </a>
```

**app.blade.php**

```
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed">
<div class="wrapper">
  @include('admin.partials.navigation.navbar')
  @include('admin.partials.sidebar.sidebar')
  @yield('content')
  @include('admin.partials.footer.footbar')
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have the view controller for sidebar and dashboard in the same file?

Comment: @UdoE. yes sidebar() function in same dashboard controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sidebar called in every blade file so you supposed to call **helper function** for it.
Change in your **composer.json** file:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ],
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

Run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Create **helpers.php** file in your app folder.

And write your function in **helpers.php** like.

```
function sidebar()
{
    $data['logos'] = Setting::first();

    return $data;
}
```

And call that function in **sidebar.php**

Comment: When i call function in blade...it says cannot re declare sidebar() previously declared

Comment: I think you've already create that function before. make sure the name should be different. make name of logo() of that function.

Comment: Nope it says same....{{(new App\helpers)->logo()}} isn't this how we call function in blade?

Comment: for whole web application functions can accessible from any blade file. If you don't know about helpers function then read a document it's necessary to use sometime

Comment: Glad to helped.

Answer (score 2):

### The `$data` you pass to `admin.layouts.app` does not exists in `sidebar`

When you `@include` a view from within a view, the framework is compiling a new view and the `$data` you passed to the first `view` does not persist to the new view, this is called a `shared view`.

There are a few solutions for your problem, from fastest to finest:

### 1) passing it directly to the shared view

```php
@include('admin.partials.sidebar.sidebar', ['logos' => $logos])
```

This will "share" the data the `shared view` needs. It goes without saying this is not the best solution.

### 2) the `->share()` method

In your controller, do this:

```php
view()->share('logos', Setting::first());
```

This will create the `$logos` variable in all the views, including the shared views. Place the call inside a service provider maybe and you won't have duplicated code.

### 3) View Composers

This is the extra fine solution, if you have an interest in it, please read this article on [View Composers](https://scotch.io/tutorials/sharing-data-between-views-using-laravel-view-composers)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Provider and Composer to achieve your goal

**Step One**

First Create a Composer class in `App\Http\View\composers` directory If you already don't have this directory you can create one

There create a File `SidebarComposer` There you have to assign your data to `compose` method. Below I share a full composer code

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\View\composers;

use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Models\SideMenu;

class SidebarComposer
{
    protected $sidemenuItems;

    public function __construct(SideMenu $SideMenu)
    {
        $this->sidemenuItems = $SideMenu::getAll();
    }

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('menuItems', $this->sidemenuItems);
    }
}
```

Here I call `Model` to get data but you can call anything you like your `controller` or `repository`

**Step Two:**

Create a service provider. You can create it Manually but I would suggest to do it by command

```
php artisan make:provider SidebarServiceProvider
```

Then register your service provider in `config/app.php`

Your service provider, you will find `boot` Method there you have to call `view::composer` to pass your data into your view

```
public function boot()
{
    View::composer('incl.sidebar', SidebarComposer::class);
}
```